# Using when working with SQLCommand/Connection

Tags: c#, sql, dispose, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I`ve used a function to open sql connection and generate a command.So I don`t use using for them.
But what happens if I get an exception ?while catch the exception nedd I explicitly dispose them?

Comment: Yes, in particular the SqlConnection but also the SqlCommand. However it is not clear why opening a SqlConnection in function precludes the using statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using` translates into `try-finally` block. If you don't want to use `using` statement then you can mimic the same using `try-finally`, in your case with `catch` just have `finally` block and dispose the connection there. Something like:

```
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
    try
    {
        //your code
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        //handle particular exception first
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        //handle all other exceptions
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

That will ensure the disposal of connection in case of an exception and normal flow *(when no exception occurs)*